# how to prove that the volume of unit hypersphere is max when dimension is 5?

Tags: geometry

Given the volume formula of unit hypersphere
$V\left(n\right) = \left(2/d\right)\left[\pi^{d/2}\,/\,\Gamma\left(d/2\right)\right]$:

- How do one prove that the max volume occurs when $d = 5\, ?$.
- I try the ratio $V\left(n\right)/V\left(n - 1\right)$ and see when this is smaller than $1$ but ends up with something like
  $\Gamma\left(d - 1/2\right)/\Gamma\left(d/2\right)$ which I am not sure how to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to work with the ratio
$$ \frac{V(n)}{V(n-2)} = \frac{2\pi}{n}. $$

Using this ratio you cannot compare an odd dimension hypersphere with an even-dimension hypersphere, but you **can** find the largest odd-dimension hypersphere and the largest even-dimension hypersphere.
Then you just need to find the sizes of those two hyperspheres (working your way upward from low dimensions whose "volumes" you know)
to determine that the odd-dimensioned one (dimension $n=5$)
is larger than the even-dimensioned one
and therefore is the largest over all dimensions.